# How do I get it to stop telling me " 'int' object has no attribute 'forward' on line 184."?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to make a face, but this problem keeps showing up and I don't know what to do. Please help, this is homework!

```
import turtle
background = turtle.Screen()
background.bgcolor("#000080")

head = turtle.Turtle()
head.color('#F5DEB3')
head.pensize(10)

left_neck = turtle.Turtle()
left_neck.color('#F5DEB3')
left_neck.pensize(15)


head.up()
head.forward(200)
head.left(90)
head.down()
head.begin_fill()
head.circle(200)
head.end_fill()

left_neck.up()
left_neck.right(65)
left_neck.forward(200)
left_neck.down()
turn = 3
for left_neck in range(5):
  left_neck.forward(5)
  left_neck.left(curve+1)
```

"

Comment: `for left_neck in range(5):` what do you want that line to do? You're overwritting `left_neck` with an integer inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The line `for left_neck in range(5):` calls the loop with the `left_neck` variable set to the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 (which are the values returned by `range(5)`).

The error you are getting is because you are trying to call the `forward` method on one of these numbers (an `int`) which does not have a `forward` method.

I presume that what you are trying to do is run the loop 5 times and use the number (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4) as the `curve` variable:

```
for curve in range(5):
  left_neck.forward(5)
  left_neck.left(curve+1)
```